# Swift adding a view over other views

Tags: swift, view, alert

I am working on a iPad app using split view controller. The problem is I have used a customised alert view, but it only align center in the detail view(Image1).  Is there any way to make the alert window align center in the whole view,just like Image2(not just detail controller).

I have customised the UIView as alert view and add it to the parentView but I dont know how to find the view over master and detail view. Thanks

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: why would you make a custom alert view in the first place? What's the original one missing?

Comment: Because I will add image to alertView and change the font size etc. later but the original alertViewController is hard to modifiy

Comment: okay. To which view did you add the custom AlertView? I assume you added it to the detail View controller? Try adding it to the Root View Controller instead?

Comment: I tried that but not working. The problem is that i cannot find a view over master and detail view controller